# I want to put exception in the method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult LoginPost(string Username, string Password)
{
    User user = dbcontext.User.Where(m => m.Username == Username).FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null && user.IsPWValid(Password))
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", user.Id);
        TempData["Error"] = "";
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Error"] = "Try again";
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }
}
```

I want to put exception in this method in ASP.NeET Entity Framework. How to put exception?

Comment: in which method ?

Comment: LoginPost method

Comment: What do you mean by "put exception"? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a try-catch to catch an exception. Perhaps, like:

```
        public IActionResult LoginPost(string Username, string Password)
        {
            User user = dbcontext.User.Where(m => m.Username == Username).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null && user.IsPWValid(Password))
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", user.Id);
                    TempData["Error"] = "";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    TempData["Error"] = "Exception occured: " + e;
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
                }
            }

            else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "Try again";
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't get it. You're catching an exception, not "putting" it (whatever that means)